# How do I calculate the distances between a varied location and fixed coordinates?

Tags: matlab, grid, coordinates, distance

I have four supply stations (**S1, S2, S3 S4**) and End Point (**EU**) with fixed coordinates on a grid as follows.

```
% Grid Definition
n = 10;             % Number of grids in the x-direction
x = 50;             % Dimension of a grid in the x-direction
k = 8;              % Number of grids in the y-direction
y = 50;             % Dimension of a grid in the x-direction
% Location of stations (coordinates)
S1 = [100 20];
S2 = [20 150];
S3 = [50 450];
S4 = [150 450];
% Location of the End User
EU = [7000 200];
```

The distribution center (**DC**) collects supplies from the four stations and route it to EU. The distance from **DC** to **Point A** is fixed at **100 meters**. The intention is to vary the location of the DC (*while others have fixed coordinates*). How do I write a code to ***calculate the distances (d1,d2,d3,d4) from S1, S2, S3, S4 to DC and (d5) Point A to EU for each location of DC***. I am still new to Matlab and can't seem to figure this out yet.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. Why aren't the S1 ans S2 points on the grid (shouldn't all coordinates be a coefficient of 50) ? By distance do you mean distance on the grid ? or just the Euclidean distance?

Comment: Hi Shervin. Thank you for your prompt response. I mean the linear distance. So I would say the Euclidean distance. I tried attaching a sketch but the site wouldn't allow me until I have at least 10 representation.

Comment: Yeah you worded it very confusingly. Can you generate the output that you expect?

Comment: Where is Point A?  Is this given, or do you have to calculate it?

Comment: Jeff - Point A is given as 100 meters to the right of DC and it's in between the distribution center DC and the EU.                                                                  Krisdestruction - I am sorry for the mix up. I wish I could upload a sketch. The DC is more like a hub where the 4 stations are connected and has a linear connection to the EU. The output I want to generate is the distance of each station to the DC and Point A to EU. Point A is in between DC and EU. I hope this helps clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following code. Since as per your information both A and DC positions are not fixed, I assumed A as fixed for the moment. Let me know if it does not suite your requirement.

```
clear all;

s1 = [100 20];
s2 = [20 150];
s3 = [50 450];
s4 = [150 450];
s = [s1; s2; s3; s4];
eu = [7000 200];
a = [5000 200];
d = 200;
plot(s(:,1),s(:,2),'r*',a(1,1),a(1,2),'g*',eu(1,1),eu(1,2),'b*');
hold on;
axis equal;

for ang = 0:pi/4:2*pi
    dc = [a(1,1)+d*sin(ang) a(1,2)+d*cos(ang)];
    plot(dc(1,1),dc(1,2),'ro');
    d1((ang/(pi/4))+1) = pdist([s1; dc],'euclidean');
    d2((ang/(pi/4))+1) = pdist([s2; dc],'euclidean');
    d3((ang/(pi/4))+1) = pdist([s3; dc],'euclidean');
    d4((ang/(pi/4))+1) = pdist([s4; dc],'euclidean');
    d5((ang/(pi/4))+1) = pdist([a; eu],'euclidean');
end

legend('S', 'A', 'EU', 'DC');
hold off;
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
xlim([0 7000]);
ylim([-500 2000]);
title('Center locations');

angx = [0:pi/4:2*pi];
figure;
plot(angx,d1,'r.:',angx,d2,'ro:',angx,d3,'r+:',angx,d4,'r*:',angx,d5,'bd--');
legend('d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4','d5');
xlabel('angle (rad)');
ylabel('distance (m)');
xlim([0 2*pi]);
ylim([1500 5500]);
set(gca,'XTick',0:pi/4:2*pi);
title('Distance vs. location');
```

**Positions**

[image]

**Distances**

[image]

Comment: Hi Hwathanie, thank you very much for your help. I understand the first graph, but not much of the second. Then is there a way to generate the various distances in a table format? For example, for a particular location of the DC, the various distances. And if we can iterate say for 10 different locations of the DC. At the end, I am trying to calculate and compare the cost for each option based on the various lengths of pipe.

Comment: I updated the code a little for the image clarity. Second graph shows how the distances change with the position change of DC. Yes, now you may change position of A and DC as you want, then you can easily plot the changes you want.

Comment: Thank you Hwathanie! I understand better now. I appreciate.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it solved your requirement.